# Adicionar zeros a direita TextBox C#

Tags: c#, validação, textbox

Tenho um `TextBox` que só aceita números decimais.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem as vezes o usuário faz o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como fazer para no evento `Leave` do `TextBox` ele adicionar os dois zeros a direita, no caso da imagem acima, de forma que o número fique assim *15,00*?

Já tentei varias formas com o seguinte código:

```
private void textBoxPercRedBCICMS_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxPercRedBCICMS.Text = String.Format("{0:##,##}", textBoxPercRedBCICMS.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei a solução, então achei melhor eu mesmo criar a resposta para ajudar os que estiverem com o mesmo problema.

Fonte da onde tirei a solução: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215989/textbox-for-price-cash-currency-on-c-sharp) e [Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Código:

```
private void textBoxPercRedBCICMS_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double value;
    if (Double.TryParse(textBoxPercRedBCICMS.Text, out value))
        textBoxPercRedBCICMS.Text = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"), "{0:F}", value);
    else
        textBoxPercRedBCICMS.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Caso você queira adicionar "R$" é só trocar esta parte: `{0:F}` por esta: `{0:C2}`

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode fazer assim:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, vou testar aqui. Valeu....

Comment: @Robss70 Disponha. A forma como você fez é bem mais apropriada pro teu caso.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox1.Text = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text).ToString("N2");
}
```